# For different code there is different answer: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am using Meteor in my project. After adding

```
paidOrFree: paidOrFree,
timesOpen: timesOpen,
publicBusiness: publicBusiness,
comments: comments
```

in my .js file when I click a button to add marker on the map I am getting this error

> "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at
>   Object.EJSON.clone (ejson.js?hash=0f17ced…:492)"

```
Template.mapForm.events({
  'submit #mapForm': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("User Position is Stored as: "+JSON.stringify(Session.get('position')));
    var position = Session.get('position');
    Markers.insert({
      lat: position.lat,
      lng: position.lng,
      image: './marker.png',
      paidOrFree: paidOrFree,
      timesOpen: timesOpen,
      publicBusiness: publicBusiness,
      comments: comments
    });
  }
});
```

also using same ids for below .js file too

```
Template.comments.events = {
  'click #submit' : function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var paidOrFree = $('#paidOrFree').val();
    var timesOpen = $('#timesOpen').val();
    var publicBusiness = $('#publicBusiness').val();
    var comments = $('#comments').val();
    Markers.insert({
      paidOrFree: paidOrFree,
      timesOpen: timesOpen,
      publicBusiness: publicBusiness,
      comments: comments,
      users: {
        _id: Meteor.userId(),
        email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address
      }
    });
    $('#paidOrFree, #timesOpen, #publicBusiness, #comments').val('');
    $('#imageModal').closeModal();
  }
}
```

HTML file which contain Form

```
<template name= "comments">
    <form>
      <label>Paid or Free:
      <input type="text" id="paidOrFree" />
    </label>
    <label>Times Open:
      <input type="text" id="timesOpen" />
    </label>
    <label>Public or Business:
      <input type="text" id="publicBusiness" />
    </label>
    <label>Comments:
    <textarea id="comments"></textarea>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
    </template>
```

Comment: How do you get these values `paidOrFree`, `timesOpen`, `publicBusiness`, `comments` inside submit `#mapForm` handler?

Comment: They're there so they get created once a marker is created. So I can put the information into it in the `Template.comments.events`